# Multiple Try/Except blocks

Tags: python, try-catch

I have multiple try/except blocks in a program where I am analyzing a dictionary input from another module. I basically use the try/except (EAFP) to check if a certain key is in the input (otherwise, I want to raise an error).

I was wondering if there is a more general approach.
Instead of

```
try:
    xyz = a['some_key']
except:
    print_error("Key 'some_key' was not defined")
```

dozens of times, if there was a way to do something like

```
try:
    xyz = a['some_key']
    xyz2 = a['some_key2']
    ...
except:
    print_error("The key(s) that were not included were some_key, some_key2")
```

Comment: No, there isn't; if the assignment to `xyz` raises an error, the assignment to `xyz2` will never be attempted. You may be able to use some kind of loop, but without more information it's hard to say. Also, note that a bare `except` is very bad practice.

Comment: Not with Python's standard capabilities.

Comment: So there is no way to delegate errors to a buffer/queue without your own special implementation?

Comment: What do you mean? What Queue? Your question has very little context and a very abstract example, so it's hard to say what you need.

Comment: So you want to catch all the exceptions and reraise/log/print them at the end?

Comment: Yes. I was asking about an implementation where I could queue up exceptions (to maintain order) then print them afterwards. I believe that NightShadeQueen answered my actual question, I was just following up with a more abstract/general question.

It might be useful to note that, through my research, it appears there isn't a way to do this.


@Jonrsharpe Yes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
borked_keys = set()
for key in list_of_keys_needed:
    try:
       xyz = a[key]
    except KeyError:
       borked_keys.add(key)

#python3 variant
print("The following keys were missing:", ",".join(borked_keys))
#or, as suggested by jonrsharpe
if borked_keys: raise KeyError(",".join(str(i) for i in borked_keys))

#python 2 variant
print "The following keys were missing: " + ",".join(borked_keys)
#or 
if borked_keys: raise KeyError ",".join(str(i) for i in borked_keys)

#if the keys are already strings, you can just use ",".join(borked_keys).
```

Comment: You could also have `if borked_keys: raise ...`